# How to get the URL connection result in a string?

Tags: java, json, yahoo-api

I'm working on Yahoo boss API. The URL supposed to return JSON, I need to store it in a string then parse it. http://developer.yahoo.com/java/howto-parseRestJava.html

My question: How can I save URL response in a string ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);//send a request and receive a response
        System.out.println("HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            // Read the content stream
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();





            // convert content stream to a String
            String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
            instream.close();
            resultString = resultString.substring(1,resultString.length()-1); // remove wrapping "[" and "]"
```

and here is the function `convertStreamToString`

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you want to wrap an appropriately configured InputStreamReader around the URL InputStream and copy the Reader to a StringWriter (apache commons IO has a "[copy Reader to String](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.Reader%29)" utility method).  However, in order to determine the correct character set for the InputStreamReader, you need to parse the ContentType header.  In which case you might be better off working with a higher level library like apache commons HttpClient.

Or, you could wrap a JSONTokener around the URL InputStream and parse the JSONObject directly from the JSONTokener (although i'm not entirely sure how the tokener determines the correct character set, so you might be safer using something like HttpClient).

Comment: If you can provide example code for copying the Reader to StringWriter that would help.